# Meteor.js : performance issue when using paginated-subscription with larger dataset

Tags: pagination, meteor

I am building an application that should be able to list several thousand articles with pagination/ infinite scrolling. The user should be able to filter/ sort this list, and currently I am experiencing performance problems when sorting articles.

I set up a very basic application to demonstrate the problem: http://meteor-paginated-subscription-example.meteor.com/ (see Github: https://github.com/lacco/meteor-paginated-subscription-example ). If you open the Firefox/ Chrome console and click on "created at"/ "priority" to initiate the sorting, you see that `Template.articles.rendered` is called several hundred times on one click. You also see that the table takes some time to be "final", during loading and rendering the order of the rows changes very often.

I am sure that I am doing some crap in my code, but I can't figure it out where the cause of my problems is. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The collection.cursor, `Models.Articles.find({}, ...)`, is a reactive data source.  Any change to the items in that cursor will cause the template `articles_table` and the subtemplates inside `{{#each articles}} to rerender.

Your resort leads to changing your data subscription so the client calls the servers asking for new data.  The flickering you see is caused by displaying the resorted intermediate steps as new data arrives and old data is deleted.  Try checking `if handle.ready()` before returning anything from the helper `Template.articles_table.articles` so the table is only displayed when your dataset is complete.

Update:  In response to additional function requests in the comments.  If you store "previousSort" and also store "previousLimit" whenever the sort or limit changes you can display your old query with reactivity turned off while the client waits for for the subscription to become ready:

```
if ( handle.ready() ){
  return Models.Articles.find({}, {sort: sort, limit: limit});
}    
else {
  return Models.Articles.find({}, {sort: previousSort, limit: previousLimit, reactive: false});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how could I handle then the load more button? If ```Template.articles_table.articles``` returns nothing while loading, then the page would be emptied when hitting "Load more". And I think that this is not an acceptable for the user...

Comment: I would make that a separate question.  Other than only changing the sort order of the the data you have ( probably not what you want ) you will need some logic to only display the new data in the new order once after it is loaded.  Checking if the subscription handle is ready is the most basic way to handle this. As you add additional function, the code and if logic would need to get more complex but you would still want to check that you had all your data before sorting and displaying to the client.

Comment: Could you provide a simple idea to get pagination & filtering working at the same time? You are right that my question doesn't explicitly covers this, but since my example application already handles both cases, I think it would be valid to answer it here.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I am not sure what 'working' means in this context.  Your question seems to be more about what to display during page loading or infinite scroll.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion (except the part with returning the non-reactive collection): https://github.com/lacco/meteor-paginated-subscription-example/commit/c2a8f9bb9ac8df4d739f82634b02e0267fa53b46 , but I am still experiencing the flickering :(. I also updated http://meteor-paginated-subscription-example.meteor.com/ . Am I doing something wrong?